# JQuery deferred with .each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Any ideas how you might use JQuery's deferred methods with a function that detects all changed forms and submits each one as an Ajax post?

I can get the same thing working if I just list a load of form submissions but if I use...

```
$('form.changed').each(function(){
  return $(this).submitWithAjax();
});
```

A fuller version of the code that I'm trying to get working is here...
[at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLhNw/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  I'm not sure I understand (but I'm pretty sure my answer is off base ...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of ".each()", use ".map()":

```
var deferreds = $('form.changed').map(function(i, elem) {
  return $(this).submitWithAjax();
});

$.when.apply(null, deferreds.get()).then(function() { ... });
```

The "$.when()" thing lets you bundle up a bunch of deferred objects and wait for all of them to succeed (or for any to fail — note the difference there). It normally allows an arbitrary number of arguments, but since we've got an array I used "apply()".

Note that I've only used this stuff lightly, so read the jQuery API docs to double check :-) *edit* — also upon re-reading your question, I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for your help. Just trying to understand why it works now.

Comment: The "Deferred" feature is one of those things that's pretty simple, but I agree that it's really hard to totally "get" exactly how the mechanism works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Delegating the change event to the form fields could solve your problem here.

```
$('form').delegate('input[type=text], input[type=radio], select', 'change', 
function(evt){
    // your submits here
    console.log('changed!')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but detecting the changes on the form wasn't the problem.

'$("form :input").live('change', function(){
      // If a form input changes
      $(this).closest('form').addClass("changed");
    });'